# How to Extract URL content using Rails or Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have this question its easy to add content to url but how to extract it

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/wish?url=file:///Users/ruelnopal/Desktop/sitetest/index.html&image=http://zalora-media-live-ph.s3.amazonaws.com/product/89/6948/1.jpg&price=PHP%C2%A0799.00&desc=Polo%20shirt%20with%20contrast%20tip,%20Collared%20neckline,%20Unlined,%20Regular%20fit&title=Pique%20Tipping%20Polo%20Shirt&display=popup
```

im trying to extract the **url**, **image**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
const queryString = location.search.substring(1) //the part after the "?"
const queryParams = queryString.split('&')
//Creates a mapping of params to values
const query = new Map(queryParams.map(param => param.split('=')))
console.log(query.get('url')) //"file:///Users/ruelnopal/Desktop/sitetest/index.html"
console.log(query.get('image')) //"http://zalora-media-live-ph.s3.amazonaws.com/product/89/6948/1.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will return all params in the URL

```
function getUrlParams(url) {

  // get query string from url (optional) or window
  var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);

  // we'll store the parameters here
  var obj = {};

  // if query string exists
  if (queryString) {

    // stuff after # is not part of query string, so get rid of it
    queryString = queryString.split('#')[0];

    // split our query string into its component parts
    var arr = queryString.split('&');

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      // separate the keys and the values
      var a = arr[i].split('=');

      // in case params look like: list[]=thing1&list[]=thing2
      var paramNum = undefined;
      var paramName = a[0].replace(/\[\d*\]/, function(v) {
        paramNum = v.slice(1,-1);
        return '';
      });

      // set parameter value (use 'true' if empty)
      var paramValue = typeof(a[1])==='undefined' ? true : a[1];

      // (optional) keep case consistent
      paramName = paramName.toLowerCase();
      paramValue = paramValue.toLowerCase();

      // if parameter name already exists
      if (obj[paramName]) {
        // convert value to array (if still string)
        if (typeof obj[paramName] === 'string') {
          obj[paramName] = [obj[paramName]];
        }
        // if no array index number specified...
        if (typeof paramNum === 'undefined') {
          // put the value on the end of the array
          obj[paramName].push(paramValue);
        }
        // if array index number specified...
        else {
          // put the value at that index number
          obj[paramName][paramNum] = paramValue;
        }
      }
      // if param name doesn't exist yet, set it
      else {
        obj[paramName] = paramValue;
      }
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) module

```
require "open-uri"

File.open('my_image.png', 'wb') do |fo|
    fo.write open("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png").read
end
```